# Iterate through two objects in Handlebars

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have a backbone model that I'm trying to extract specific values from. Something like: (using raw Object but assume its a backbone Model)

```
var x = {
    primary : ["a","b","c"],
    attributes : {
        a : 1,
        b : 2,
        d : 4
    }
}
```

In the end, it should render `1 2`

I'm thinking something like

```
{{#each primary}}
    {{#if attributes[this]}}{{attributes[this]}}{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Ideas?

Comment: You're usually better off doing the data wrangling and manipulation in plain JavaScript before you get to the templates when using Handlebars. Reformat your data so that you can do simple iterations inside the template.

Comment: Don't forget that there is a method `model.toJSON()` for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`lookup`](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) helper made for it:

> The lookup helper allows for dynamic parameter resolution using Handlebars variables. This is useful for resolving values for array indexes.

```js
var source = $("#template").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

var data = {
  primary : ["a","b","c"],
  attributes : {
      a : 1,
      b : 2,
      d : 4
  }
};

$('body').append(template(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#primary}}
 {{lookup ../attributes this}}
{{/primary}}
</script>
```